# Typescript: Type of nested, optional Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

having the following interface defined:

```
interface MyComplexType {
  relations?: {
    foo?: { x: string; y: string }[];
    bar?: { a: string; b: string }[];
  }
}
```

Now I want to define a variable with the type of a `foo` row:

```
  const myFoo?: MyComplexType['relations']['foo'][number];
  // Error: Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{ foo?: { x: string; x: string }[], bar?:....
```

Got this workarounded by doing

```
  const myFoo?: NonNullable<
                  NonNullable<
                    MyComplexType['relations']
                  >['foo']
                >[number];
```

Is there a more beautiful way? :-)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW you could just alias it to a shorter name:

```
type N<T> = NonNullable<T>;

let myFoo1: N<N<MyComplexType["relations"]>["foo"]>[number];
```

orrrr make a DeepRequired type:

```
type DeepRequired<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: DeepRequired<T[K]> };

let myFoo2: DeepRequired<MyComplexType>["relations"]["foo"][number];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DCB7AtgBwBsIAPAFXXxQG8AoZB5KCQuMYbEAZwH4AuZHUbDkMbNn6DkJAVzBRQAcwDcydLPlLkAXwDaAXWX0RDAEZwok6sjgaFIFclN2tew8Ybaj22rTCUUADkAHjIAPmQAXmRAzkCAV0JWU2JQsKNaYjBkXHQAMXEARgEQkIwcAmJyAN0AImZWdk4uWv0wurFsVvaQeNxTaHc-AOQAEQgIfAAlCABHeOBmABM0qKldAGlkUGQAawh0bBhkMn0AWklxyZn5xYgVsk22nQz-KmQADTWr6bmF5eC5TwRFIFCo6V8WRy+XEACYBD8bv97oCsMCqmCIO16iw2BxuK0OuJCb1+oMjEA)